# Función para generar una tabla de contenidos 'TOC' en un notebook de jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, json, jupyter

Si introducimos la salida de la siguiente función, en una celda markdown de un notebook, nos genera una  tabla de contenidos 'TOC'.

```
# Sin índices y subíndices.
import urllib, json
def generate_toc(notebook_path, indent_char="&emsp;"):
    is_markdown = lambda it: "markdown" == it["cell_type"]
    is_title = lambda it: it.strip().startswith("#") and it.strip().lstrip("#").lstrip()
    with open(notebook_path, 'r') as in_f:
        nb_json = json.load(in_f)
    for cell in filter(is_markdown, nb_json["cells"]):
        for line in filter(is_title, cell["source"]):
            line = line.strip()
            indent = indent_char * (line.index(" ") - 1)
            title = line.lstrip("#").lstrip()
            url = urllib.parse.quote(title.replace(" ", "-"))
            out_line = f"{indent}[{title}](#{url})<br>\n"
            print(out_line, end="")

# Ejemplo de uso
path = '/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2023/Trabajo estadística/2 Estadistica_Inferencial_probabilidad_2.0.ipynb'
generate_toc(path)
```

Su problema, para mi, es que no incluye numeración de índices y subíndices. Intento mejorar esta función  sugerida por [noob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6787976/noob) en [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151450/how-can-i-add-a-table-of-contents-to-a-jupyter-jupyterlab-notebook/59286150#59286150), para que la tabla de contenidos tenga índices y subíndices.

```
import urllib
import json

def generate_toc(notebook_path, indent_char="&emsp;"):
    is_markdown = lambda it: "markdown" == it["cell_type"]
    is_title = lambda it: it.strip().startswith("#") and it.strip().lstrip("#").lstrip()

    with open(notebook_path, 'r') as in_f:
        nb_json = json.load(in_f)

    toc_numbers = []  # Lista para llevar el conteo de los números de contenido en cada nivel

    for cell in filter(is_markdown, nb_json["cells"]):
        for line in filter(is_title, cell["source"]):
            line = line.strip()
            title = line.lstrip("#").lstrip()

            level = line.count("#")  # Nivel del título según la cantidad de "#"

            if level > len(toc_numbers):
                toc_numbers.append(1)  # Agregar un nuevo nivel con numeración inicial en 1
            else:
                toc_numbers[level - 1] += 1  # Incrementar el número de contenido en el nivel actual
                toc_numbers[level:] = [1] * (len(toc_numbers) - level)  # Reiniciar numeración en niveles inferiores

            toc_number_str = ".".join(str(num) for num in toc_numbers[:level])
            indent = indent_char * level
            url = urllib.parse.quote(title.replace(" ", "-"))
            out_line = f"{indent}{toc_number_str} {title}(#{url})<br>\n"
            print(out_line, end="")

# Ejemplo de uso
path = '/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2023/Trabajo estadística/2 Estadistica_Inferencial_probabilidad_2.0.ipynb'
generate_toc(path)
```

Me devuelve:

```
&emsp;1 Importación de módulos(#Importaci%C3%B3n-de-m%C3%B3dulos)<br>
&emsp;2 Probabilidad.(#Probabilidad.)<br>
&emsp;&emsp;2.1 Experimento aleatorio, espacio muestral, evento(#Experimento-aleatorio%2C-espacio-muestral%2C-evento)<br>
&emsp;&emsp;2.2 Operaciones con sucesos:(#Operaciones-con-sucesos%3A)<br>
```

Si introducimos este código en una celda markdown de jupyter, la salida es:

1 Importación de módulos(#Importaci%C3%B3n-de-m%C3%B3dulos)
 2 Probabilidad.(#Probabilidad.)
  2.1 Experimento aleatorio, espacio muestral, evento(#Experimento-aleatorio%2C-espacio-muestral%2C-evento)
  2.2 Operaciones con sucesos:(#Operaciones-con-sucesos%3A)
  2.3 Espacio probabilístico asociado a un experimento aleatorio.(#Espacio-probabil%C3%ADstico-asociado-a-un-experimento-aleatorio.)
  2.4 Probabilidad de Laplace(#Probabilidad-de-Laplace)

Vemos que sobra todo el texto que se encuentra entre paréntesis. ¿Cuál es el error en el código?.¿Cómo podemos evitar este duplicado del enunciado de cada línea de contenido?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: El link no lleva a la respuesta de noob. Será este el link correcto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72666162/12913664

Comment: Podrías agregar una muestra con el archivo que estás trabajando para poder hacer pruebas por favor?

Comment: Sí, ese es el link. Intentaré colocar en algún sitio un notebook.

Comment: Te seré sincero, te quería ayudar viendo si html o markdown ofrecen una forma mejor de hacer esto (como una ordered list), pero no hace lo de 2.1, 2.2, etc. Así que te diré cual pareciera ser el error: te faltó encerrar entre corchetes el titulo, es decir, la parte que genera el item debería quedar `f"{indent}{toc_number_str} [{title}](#{url})<br>\n"`

Comment: Te recomiendo que tengas en cuenta un detalle: El caracter espacio que usas para la indentación no suele ser igual de largo que los demás caracteres. Es decir, por ejemplo el caracter "." podría medir menos que el espacio. En ese caso te recomiendo buscar otra forma de indentación (como precisamente usar orered list) o usar una fuente monoespaciada o fixed (donde todos los caracteres miden lo mismo)

Comment: Gracias Dante. Esa es la solución. Añado el código final en una respuesta nueva.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error en la lógica de tu propuesta. Si se trata de un cambio de niveles de mayor a menor, como podría ser pasar de 1.2. a 2 o de 1.1.3 a 1.2 etc, lo que hace tu codigo es incrementar en una unidad el nivel, correcto, pero luego haces un reset a 1 de los niveles anteriores. Esto en el string no se ve porque solo muestras hasta el nivel donde estás, pero en la siguiente iteración, si se trata de un nivel mayor al anterior, incrementarás en una unidad, y te saltarás un índice.

Por ejemplo para pasar de 1.2 a 2, en realidad lo que hay en la lista es 2.1, pero solo te muestra el 2, en la siguiente iteración, incrementará en 2.2, saltándose así el 2.1. Por lo tanto el reset debería ser con 0 y no 1. Aunque yo creo es más intuitivo volver a empezar

```
def generate_toc(notebook_path, indent_char="&emsp;"):
    is_markdown = lambda it: "markdown" == it["cell_type"]
    is_title = lambda it: it.strip().startswith("#") and it.strip().lstrip("#").lstrip()

    with open(notebook_path, 'r') as in_f:
        nb_json = json.load(in_f)

    toc_numbers = []  # Lista para llevar el conteo de los números de contenido en cada nivel

    for cell in filter(is_markdown, nb_json["cells"]):
        for line in filter(is_title, cell["source"]):
            line = line.strip()
            title = line.lstrip("#").lstrip()

            level = line.count("#")  # Nivel del título según la cantidad de "#"

            if level > len(toc_numbers):
                toc_numbers.append(1)  # Agregar un nuevo nivel con numeración inicial en 1
            else:
                toc_numbers[level - 1] += 1  # Incrementar el número de contenido en el nivel actual
                if level < len(toc_numbers):
                    toc_numbers = toc_numbers[:level]
            toc_number_str = ".".join(str(num) for num in toc_numbers)
            indent = indent_char * level
            url = urllib.parse.quote(title.replace(" ", "-"))
            out_line = f"{indent}{toc_number_str} [{title}](#{url})<br>\n"
            print(out_line, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementando la recomendación de Dante, el script final queda así.

```
import urllib
import json

def generate_toc(notebook_path, indent_char="&emsp;"):
    is_markdown = lambda it: "markdown" == it["cell_type"]
    is_title = lambda it: it.strip().startswith("#") and it.strip().lstrip("#").lstrip()

    with open(notebook_path, 'r') as in_f:
        nb_json = json.load(in_f)

    toc_numbers = []  # Lista para llevar el conteo de los números de contenido en cada nivel

    for cell in filter(is_markdown, nb_json["cells"]):
        for line in filter(is_title, cell["source"]):
            line = line.strip()
            title = line.lstrip("#").lstrip()

            level = line.count("#")  # Nivel del título según la cantidad de "#"

            if level > len(toc_numbers):
                toc_numbers.append(1)  # Agregar un nuevo nivel con numeración inicial en 1
            else:
                toc_numbers[level - 1] += 1  # Incrementar el número de contenido en el nivel actual
                toc_numbers[level:] = [1] * (len(toc_numbers) - level)  # Reiniciar numeración en niveles inferiores

            toc_number_str = ".".join(str(num) for num in toc_numbers[:level])
            indent = indent_char * level
            url = urllib.parse.quote(title.replace(" ", "-"))
            out_line = f"{indent}{toc_number_str} [{title}](#{url})<br>\n"
            print(out_line, end="")

# Ejemplo de uso
path = '/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2023/Trabajo estadística/2 Estadistica_Inferencial_probabilidad_2.0.ipynb'
generate_toc(path)
```